# Why Outlook.live.com and Outlook App show blank body, but the source is NOT empty?

Tags: outlook

It has been almost a week since this problem appeared.

Previously every thing was fine, I am using PHP mail function to send feedback from server to my E-mail; Then, out of a sudden, about 40% of the E-mails are shown to have no content, the server was not touched.. I opened outlook.live.com and I was able to see the message body from "show message source", which means my server hasn't changed any thing, it is still sending all the information I need, but Outlook would not show the content for some reason.

Does anyone have any idea about the cause and solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has encountered this problem, Microsoft Community has provided the valid solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/why-outlooklivecom-and-outlook-app-show-blank-body/6b8b8e2e-aee8-4473-8cf8-4fbfd4c4ad68).

> The emails we send are ascii (no formatting, not html). I added a
>   header line to our code script and it seems to be working again..
>   perhaps the requirements have changed in the last few months. If you
>   have the same issue - i suggest checking your headers to ensure they
>   are populated. `'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'."\r\n"` .